# Negation of quantified expressions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, quantifiers

Can someone explain the difference between `¬∀x P(x)` and `∀x ¬P(x)`, and also why

`¬∀xP (x) ≡ ∃x ¬P (x)` can't be written as `¬∀x P(x) ≡ ¬∃x P(x)` and vice versa.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the universe of discourse be bricks, that is, all our quantifiers are over the set of all bricks ($x$ is a brick). Let $P(x)$ be the statement that $x$ is red.

$\neg \forall x P(x)$: not all bricks are red,

$\forall x \neg P(x)$: all bricks are not red.

It should be apparent that the first statement is true but the second is false. However, the first statement *is* equivalent to

$\exists x \neg P(x)$: there is a brick that is not red,

but not

$ \neg \exists x P(x)$: there is not a red brick.

These statements are obvious once written out in plain English instead of possibly unfamiliar symbols.

Comment: I'm glad you understand it! Note that I purposefully left the explanation vague so the reader must supply it.

Comment: Yeah, it took me a while to get my head around the first two.

Comment: Thankfully it seems like you understand English to the point where the subtle syntactic differences in those sentences still holds meaning to you.